# Crop 10000x10000 image sequence to video

Tags: video, video-encoding, image-editing, crop

I have an unusually large PNG image sequence (about 10000x10000, each file is about 50MB). I want to crop a region of this (about 3000x3000) and encode it into a video. The format is not important, as long as it has decent quality and well compressed, and obviously supports that resolution.

I tried After Effect's demo, but it doesn't seem to handle well that kind of resolution on my computer. I'm open to any software, better if free. Command line is fine.

Comment: What do you mean After Effects "cannot handle" that kind of resolution? After effects does 4k all the time. Maybe you computer cannot handle it.

Comment: You're right, I edited the question. 4K is about 4000x2000 though, and the images i'm trying to load are 10000x10000, which is about 12 times larger.

Comment: how about cropping the image sequence first?

Comment: that's a good idea, but i didn't find a ffmpeg command line to do it on an image sequence. if you can point me in the right direction, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do batch cropping/editing images with [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). It is included in almost every Linux distro and has tons of options for you. It has versions for other platforms, too. Below is some examples that may help you

To simply resize all images to 3000x3000 in-place you can use

```sh
mogrify -resize 3000x3000 *.png
```

This will overwrite your files. If you want to write outputs to another folder use

```sh
mogrify -resize 3000x3000 *.png -path /path/to/output/folder
```

If mogrify is too slow or takes too much memory you could use [this way](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#read)

```sh
for f in *.png
do
    convert $f'[3000x3000]' $outputdir/$f.resized.png
done
```

If you also want to convert them to another format like jpg for reducing stress on the video encoder later:

```sh
mogrify -resize 3000x3000 -format jpg *.png
```

If you just want to crop a 3000x3000 region from offset 1000x2000 then use this

```sh
mogrify -crop 3000x3000+1000+2000 *.png
```

After all just encode the images with ffmpeg